# Can my 2nd spell used with quickened spell not be a cantrip?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, sorcerer, metamagic

I've been reading quickened spell and wanted to know if I can cast 2 times the spell Fireball because on page 102 of PHB:

> When you cast a spell that has a casting time of 1 action, you can
>   spend 2 sorcery points to change the casting time to 1 bonus action
>   for this casting.

on page 202 it states :

> A spell cast with a bonus action is especially swift. You must use a
>   bonus action on your turn to cast the spell, provided that you haven't
>   already taken a bonus action this turn. You can't cast another spell
>   during the same turn, except for a cantrip with a casting time of 1
>   action.

but we all know that Specific beats general and Quickened spell is the specific rule so there should be no problem casting 2 fireballs in my own turn?

Answer (score 16):

### No.

Quickened spell does not remove the limitation of casting a spell as a bonus action. What quickened spell does do is exactly as it says, taking a 1 action spell and making it a bonus action for this one specific casting. In the quickened spell block it does not lift the restriction for casting two spells.

Comment: If anything, the poorly written bonus action spell rule was probably written specifically to limit sorcerer shenanigans in the first place.  It's a shame that it affects all other casters.

Answer (score 1):

The "[specific beats general](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/introduction#SpecificBeatsGeneral) guideline says:

> Remember this: If a specific rule contradicts a general rule, the specific rule wins.

But in this case, the specific rule for Quickened spell allows you to cast a spell that takes an action to cast as a bonus action. This contradicts the general rule for casting time that spells which take an action to cast... take an action to cast. The rule for Quickened spell, however, does not say anything at all about how it works to cast a spell as a bonus action. There *are* general rules for that, and you've cited them — and since there's no specific rule contradicting them, they apply.

Answer (score -12):

Yes it can be but only through Readying the spell.

Actually I've found the answer and it is that yes you can cast 2 times fireball but not in the same turn, but it does not say anything in the same round.

So basically you can do Quickened Spell Fireball as a Bonus Action, then use the regular action to use Ready and Ready Fireball as a trigger of something and that's it, you won't do it in your same turn but nothing forbids you from doing it in your round (another one else's turn).

Comment: _"When you ready a spell, **you cast it as normal** but hold its energy, which you release with your reaction when the trigger occurs."_ you can't bypass the requirement like that

Comment: It also seems, from this self-answer, that your goal is to cast 2 Action spells in a round, the question doesn't ask that in its [current version](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/revisions/105165/2). If the goal is in fact to find a way to cast 2 spells in a turn (round? there are distinctions), I'd ask it in a different question, since you already got one answer that answers the question on quickened spell.